# How to use correctly useMutation from react-query, get error and success notifications?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-query

In my Next.js project, I'm using `react-query` to fetch data from MongoDB. In my form, I send a POST request with `useMutation` hook:

```js
/*** components ***/
import {Button, InputGroup} from "../index";

import {useMutation} from "react-query";
import {addUser} from "../../../utils/helpers/helper";


/*** form validation ***/
import {useFormik} from "formik";
import {validateInput} from "../../../utils/functions/validateInput";


const AddingForm = () => {

    const { mutate, status } = useMutation(addUser, {
        onSuccess: data => {
            console.log(data);
            const message = "success"
            alert(message)
        },
        onError: () => {
            alert("there was an error")
        },
        /*onSettled: () => {
            queryClient.invalidateQueries('create');
        }*/
    });

    const newUser = () => {
        mutate(formik.values)
    }

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            name: "",
            email: ""
        },
        onSubmit: newUser,
        validate: validateInput
    });



    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                <InputGroup
                    label="Name"
                    name="name"
                    error={formik.errors.name}
                    isTouched={formik.touched.name}
                    {...formik.getFieldProps("name")}
                />
                <InputGroup
                    label="Email"
                    name="email"
                    error={formik.errors.email}
                    isTouched={formik.touched.email}
                    {...formik.getFieldProps("email")}
                />

                <Button disabled={!formik.values.name && !formik.values.email}
                        className={`w-full ${!formik.values.name || !formik.values.email ? 'bg-gray-200 text-gray-500' : 'bg-orange-200'}`}
                        type="submit"
                >
                    Aggiungi
                </Button>

            </form>
        </>
    )
}

export default AddingForm;
```

Now, if I visit my `users` page, the new user is there, but I got this in the terminal console:

> API resolved without sending a response for /api/users, this may result in stalled requests.

Also, there's no `alert()` from the `onError` method inside `useMutation`. Only `onSuccess` triggers the `alert()`, but when I add a user with an already existing name. So `on Error` should trigger, but it does not. Yes, a strange behavior.

Just for completeness, this is the `addUser` function:

```js
/*** POST new user ***/
export const addUser = async (formData) => {

    try {
        
        const { response } = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/api/users`, formData);
        return response.data;

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("ERROR FROM TRY/CATCH", error.message)
        return error.message
    }
}
```

And this is the handler from `pages/api/users`:

```js
import connectDB from "../../../db/connectDB";
import {getUsers, postUser, updateUser, deleteUser} from "../../../db/controllers/AddedUserController";

/**
 * @param {import('next').NextApiRequest} req
 * @param {import('next').NextApiResponse} res
 */

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    await connectDB().catch(() => res.status(405).json({error: "Connection Error"}))

    const {method} = req

    switch(method) {
        case "GET":
            await getUsers(req, res)
            break;
        case "POST":
            await postUser(req, res)
            break;
        case "PUT":
            await updateUser(req, res)
            break;
        case "DELETE":
            await deleteUser(req, res)
            break;
        default:
            res.setHeader("Allow", ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"])
            res.status(405).end(`Method ${method} not allowed`)
    }
}
```

This is `postUser`:

```
/*** POST http://localhost:3000/api/users ***/
export async function postUser(req, res) {

    try {
        console.log("FORM DATA", req.body)

        if(!req.body || req.body === undefined) return res.status(404).json({error: "Form data not provided"})

        await AddedUser.create(req.body);

    } catch(error) {
        res.status(404).json({error: error.message})
    }
}
```

I would be glad to know if I'm doing something wrong with `useMutation` or if I'm missing something somewhere.

***My goals are:***

*1. fetching data (the problem now is with POST request) correctly using `react-query`*

*2. find a way to show a success/error notification for both cases, using `react-query`*

Comment: Can you show `postUser`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using mutation here? If you're requesting data from the backend (whether with a get or a post or some other API entirely) you probably want to useQuery here rather than useMutation.

Comment: Yes I was looking around about using `useQuery`, I'll try now thanks!

Comment: yousoumar,  I've added `postUser` in the **EDIT**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of errors here. First, to let `react-query` handles when there is an error, remove the `try-catch` you have in `addUser`:

```js
export const addUser = async (formData) => {
  const { data } = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/api/users`, formData);
  return data;
};
```

Then, when there is a success in `postUser`, you are not returning a result to the frontend. You can do that by changing `postUser` to:

```js
export async function postUser(req, res) {
  try {
    console.log("FORM DATA", req.body);

    if (!req.body) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "Form data not provided" });
    }

    await AddedUser.create(req.body);
    return res.status(201).json({ message: "User created with success" });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ error: error.message });
  }
}
```

Comment: You know, I was thinking about the try/catch block as the main problem, but I didn't try. Thanks man, I'll let you know

Comment: YES! now it works, thanks! So I will pay attention to try/catch blocks in the next calls.
The only thing, `addUser` has to return `response` and not `response.data` cause of destructuring I think. However it works!

Comment: You are right about `response.data`. I edited my answer. And glad I could help :)